# angular 6 bootstrap how to set width to a td table in a component template

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I work with Angular 6.

I have the following screen

[image]

This screen has two elements. An html. In this html, I have a table and after in a component, I have the td

```
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-lg table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 30%"></th>
        <th style="width: 30%">Name</th>
        <th style="width: 30%">Count Prices</th>
        <th style="width: 30%">Total Prices</th>
        <th style="width: 30%">Averages Prices</th>
        <th style="width: 30%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr *paFor="let item of getCategoriesShortName(); let i = index; let odd = odd; let even = even" [class.bg-info]="odd" 
            [class.bg-warning]="even">

      <paSummaryCategoryDisplay [pa-category]="item"></paSummaryCategoryDisplay> 
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

paSummaryCategoryDisplay  is a component

```
@Component({
  selector: "paSummaryCategoryDisplay",
  template: `   <td class="col-md-2"></td>
                <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle">
                {{item.nameCategory}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle;" >
                {{item.summaryCategory.countPrices}}</td>
                 <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle">
                {{item.summaryCategory.totalPrices}}</td>

                <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle;" >
                {{item.summaryCategory.averagePrices}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2"></td>`
})
```

How can I set the width of the td along with the html table?

**EDITED**

This is my screen modified 
[image]

This my main template

```
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-4 p-2">   

    <paCategoriesTableShort></paCategoriesTableShort>   
  </div>


</div>
```

```
@Component({
    selector: "paCategoriesTableShort",
    templateUrl: "categoriesTableShort.component.html"


})
```

**categoriesTableShort.component.html**

```
<table  class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" >

    <tr>
        <th style="width:30%"></th>
        <th style="width:30%">Name</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Count Prices</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Total Prices</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Averages Prices</th>
        <th style="width:30%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr *paFor="let item of getCategoriesShortName(); let i = index; let odd = odd; let even = even" [class.bg-info]="odd" 
            [class.bg-warning]="even">

      <paSummaryCategoryDisplay [pa-category]="item"></paSummaryCategoryDisplay> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: "paSummaryCategoryDisplay",
  template: `   <td style="width:30%"></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;width:30%">
                {{item.nameCategory}}</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;width:30%" >
                {{item.summaryCategory.countPrices}}</td>
                <td  style="vertical-align:middle;width:30%">
                {{item.summaryCategory.totalPrices}}</td>

                <td  style="vertical-align:middle;width:30%" >
                {{item.summaryCategory.averagePrices}}</td>
                <td style="width:30%"></td>`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table you have set a width of 30% on the "th" elements.
But in your "td" elements you have set the class "col-md-2".

You have set different width "behaviour" on your elements, but expect the same alignment.

Try using either "width: 30%", or "col-md-2" on **both** th and td as following

```
<th class="col-md-2"></th>
<th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
<th class="col-md-2">Count Prices</th>
<th class="col-md-2">Total Prices</th>
<th class="col-md-2">Averages Prices</th>
<th class="col-md-2"></th>
```

On another note, i would not recommend having CSS styling in the element itself, a good practice is to set the styling in a stylesheet and use classes instead

Comment: I would like to ask a question. Does it work right to have table definition in a html and td in a component template?

Comment: @Carlota Yes there should not be any difference in having it in a component or not. Though if you are **not** going to be reusing this component in other places, i would recommend skipping the component, just to simplify the code

Comment: I am goint to reuse the component in several html

Comment: @Carlota Then a component is the right way to go, please mark my answer if it solved your issue

Comment: I tried your solution but I have some troubles. I edited my code modifications

Comment: @Carlota did you find a solution?